# Can AWS Redshift drop a table that is wrapped in transaction?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

During the ETL we do the following operations:

```
    begin transaction;

    drop table if exists target_tmp;
    create table target_tmp like target;

    insert into target_tmp select * from source_a inner join source_b on ...;
    analyze table target_tmp;

    drop table target;
    alter table target_tmp rename to target;

    commit;
```

The SQL command is performed by AWS Data Pipeline, if this is important.

However, the pipelines sometimes fail with the following error:

```
    ERROR: table 111566 dropped by concurrent transaction
```

Redshift supports serializable isolation. Does one of the commands break isolation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that works, but if generating the temp table takes a while you can expect to see that error for other queries while it runs. You could try generating the temp table in a separate transaction (transaction may not be needed unless you worry about updates to the source tables). Then do a quick rotation of the table names so there is much less time for contention:

```
-- generate target_tmp first then
begin;
alter table target rename to target_old;
alter table target_tmp rename to target;
commit;
drop table target_old;
```

Comment: Thaks, I followed your advice and have not seen the error in a while. I am still not sure if the behaviour that I encountered is not a bug.

Comment: Since only the current session will reach the target_old table. It's very interesting to know why it matters, if the drop table command is after or before the commit command?

Comment: This is great. I had a quicksight view unable to obtain data until the transaction was complete for a scheduled job, this procedure fixes the problem.

Comment: Two things: I did `drop table if exists target_old;` and if generating `target_tmp` fails the alter table rename should fail too, which will abort the transaction, which is the desired result I think.